# reimport API Management APIs from Function App using Az CLI/PowerShell

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-api-management, azure-cli

I have an Azure Functions instance added to an API Management API by using "Import from Azure Functions". 
When I update my Azure Functions instance, the API Management API it's not automatically updated.
I searched everywhere for a command able to reimport my Azure Function into my API Management API, but I can't find any solution/workaround.


That's what I want to automate:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in Azure Powershell/CLI command to do that, in this case, you could simply call the REST API - [`Apis - Create Or Update`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/2019-12-01/apis/createorupdate) directly with powershell [`Invoke-AzRestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/invoke-azrestmethod?view=azps-5.8.0) or CLI [`az rest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/reference-index?view=azure-cli-latest#az_rest).

**Powershell Sample:**

```
$groupname = "xxxxxxx"
$APIMname = "joyapim"
$FullApiVersionName = "joyfunapim-v2"
$sourceApiName = "joyfunapim"
$apiVersion = "v2"

$ApiMgmtContext = New-AzApiManagementContext -ResourceGroupName $groupname -ServiceName $APIMname
$Api = Get-AzApiManagementApi -Context $ApiMgmtContext -ApiId $sourceApiName
$apiVersionSetId = (Get-AzApiManagementApiVersionSet -Context $ApiMgmtContext | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -eq $sourceApiName}).ApiVersionSetId
$Apim = Get-AzApiManagement -ResourceGroupName $groupname -Name $APIMname
$path = $Apim.Id + "/apis/" + $ApiFullVersionName + ";rev=1?api-version=2019-12-01"
$payload = @{
    "properties" = @{
        "sourceApiId" = $Api.Id
        "apiVersion" = $apiVersion
        "apiVersionSetId" = "/apiVersionSets/"+ $apiVersionSetId
        "apiVersionSet" = @{
            "versioningScheme" = "Segment"
            "name" = $sourceApiName
        }

    }
} | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10

Invoke-AzRestMethod -Path $path -Method PUT -Payload $payload
```

[image]

Check in the portal:

[image]

Comment: Nice script, but this does not solve my problem because I want to update the API Management APIs definition (new operations, methods, paths, etc) using my Azure Functions. I don't have a OpenAPI / Swagger file, but the manual import works perfect.

Comment: @johnykes I have the same requirement as yours, do we know how to go about it?